# MySQL Entity Framework EDMX update from database issue : StoreGeneratedPattern=“Identity”

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ado.net, edmx

Every time I try to update model from database, EDMX put `StoreGeneratedPattern="Identity"` as new properties for each datetime fields in EDMX file. after that, the program runs in different way.

Any version combinations of MySql connector.net & `MySql.Data` & `MySql.Data.EntityFramework` does not solve this problem at all.

**Before:**

```
<Property Name="date_start" Type="datetime" Precision="0" Nullable="false" />
```

**After:**

```
<Property Name="date_start" Type="datetime" Precision="0" StoreGeneratedPattern="Identity" Nullable="false" />
```

Environment:

- VS2019 V16.9.2
- ASP.NET MVC Framework project
- V8.0.21 combinations of MySql.Data & .Entity Framework & connector.net

Please help!